# Passing data from MyScene to ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my MyScene.h I have `@property (nonatomic) int topScore;`
In MyScene.m I have `self.topScore = 10;`

I'm trying to get that topScore to show up in my ViewController class by `#importing "MyScene.h"` and declaring `MyScene *_myScene` and doing `int topScore = _myScene.topScore;`

I keep getting 0. How do I properly pass an integer value or any values from one class to another?

Comment: You declared _myScene, but did you ever assign it to the instance of MyScene that you have? A property doesn't  point to anything until you assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question there is two question you asked

1. You put an object of **MyScene** in **ViewController** class. No Integer is being passed here:

   *Solution for getting zero:* you maybe forget to initialize the **MyScene** object inside the ViewController, which can cause such an error.
2. To pass a value (object / non-object) type to another viewController you should declare in **ViewController.h** a property of your data passing type.

-If passing data is a object type then you could set it as a property like following:

```
@interface ViewControlle : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
```

then when you wanna pass this value to the **viewController** just set the property from outside like the following:

```
ViewController *VcObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];
VcObj.name = @"My Name is Anthony";
//whatever the way you wanna show the view - push in the navigationController or show Modally o
```

In the implementation of the **ViewController.m** in **ViewDidAppear** you must set the view's (UILabel, UITextField) property with the values of the **name's** value like following:

```
-(void) ViewDidAppear{
[super ViewDidAppear];
self.myLabel.text = name; //here assumed that you have a UILabel declared as myLabel
}
```

My suggestion is **ViewDidAppear** because it called every time whenever the view comes up in the screen, If any **ViewController** is embedded within a tab-bar (UITabBarController) the **viewDidLoad** won't called each and every time. Otherwise instead of Tab-bar case **ViewDIdLoad** method can be used.

Comment: `ViewController *VcObj = [[ViewController alloc]init];` worked for me

Comment: So it was solution 1, that you forget to initialize the **ViewController**, carry on bro , i had also stuck on a similar issue. Happy coding :) .